# Reloading Angular app running in docker gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: angular, docker, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing an Angular app and the BE is in Java/Spring-Boot. Somehow I'm able to perform reload or simply copy de address directly in the browser in every view but /management/**.

[www.site-name.com/inscription](http://www.site-name.com/inscription) (work)
[www.site-name.com/management/utilisateurs](http://www.site-name.com/management/utilisateurs) (not work)

These are my routing configs in Angular

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: IntroPageComponent,
        canActivate: [HomeGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../user-auth/').then(module => module.UserAuthModule),
    },
    {
        path: 'inscription',
        loadChildren: () => import('../inscription').then(module => module.InscriptionModule),
        canActivateChild: [AuthenticatedGuard, InscriptionGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'management',
        loadChildren: () => import('../management').then(module => module.ManagementModule),
        canActivateChild: [AuthenticatedGuard, ManagementGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/home'
    }
];
```

Then Management module has its own routing configs

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'utilisateurs',
    component: UsersComponent,
    resolve: { man : ManagementPreload }
  },
  "more routes here"
];
```

Spring controller which provides the index.html

```
 @GetMapping({
            "/",
            "/home",
            "/incription", 
            "/management/**",
            ......
    })
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

And dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG APP_NAME
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar", "--file:/app/config/application-siteinscription.properties", "-XX:+UseG1GC"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure what the problem was and implement a solution which I'm not sure if it's the most appropriate one, but I will post it here for others with the same problem and maybe to get some feedback on how to implement a better solution.

Worth mention that nothing was wrong with the angular routing configs.

The problem is related to SpringMVC ViewResolver(s)

Based on my config

```
 @GetMapping({
            "/",
            "/home",
            "/incription", 
            "/management/**",
            ......
    })
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

When Spring ViewResolver sees a route like

```
/management/**
```

it will try to find the view index and return it based on configs something like

```
/path/to/resource/management/index.html
```

And all I need is really no matter what the route is always return

```
/path/to/resource/index.html
```

The way I managed to make the app work as I needed without a lot of overhead was simply to implement the controller like

```
@GetMapping({
        "/",
        "/home",
        "/auth",
        "/inscription",
        ...
})
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/management/**")
public ModelAndView forwardToHome() {
    return new ModelAndView("forward:/home", new ModelMap());
}
```